# Nondeterministic growth in Julia loop

Tags: julia

I have a computation loop **with adaptive time stepping** and I need to store the results at each iteration. In other words, I do not know the vector size before the computation, so I can not preallocate a vector size to store the data. Right now, I build a vector using the `push!` function

```
function comp_loop()
    clock = [0.0]
    data = [0.0]
    while run_time < model_time
    
        # Calculate new timestep
        timestep = rand(Float64)  # Be sure to add Random
        run_time += timestep
    
        # Build vector
        push!(clock,run_time)
        push!(data,timestep)
        
    end
end
```

Is there a more efficient way to go about this? Again, I know the optimal choice is to preallocate the vector, but I do not have that luxury available. Buffers are theoretically not an option either, as I don't now how large to make them. I'm looking for something more "optimal" on how to implement this in Julia (i.e. maybe some advanced application available in the language).

Comment: Congrats on being the first question asked after the outage

Comment: If you have a rough idea about how big your final arrays will be, you can use `sizehint!`. You can just set that and not think more about it, it doesn't matter if you over- or underestimate the size, but if you have the right order of magnitude, you could avoid a larger number of reallocations. Though, as @phipsgabler says,  `push!` is also clever about its allocations.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, you can use a linked list such as the one from [DataStructures.jl](https://juliacollections.github.io/DataStructures.jl/latest/linked_list/) to get O(1) appending.  And then optionally write that out to a `Vector` afterwards (probably in reverse order, though).

In practise, `push!`ing to a `Vector` is often efficient enough -- `Vector`s use a doubling strategy to manage their dynamic size, which leads to amortized constant time *and* the advantage of contiguous memory access.

So you could try the linked list, but be sure to benchmark whether it's worth the effort.

Now, the above is about time complexity.  When you care about allocation, the argument is quite similar; with a vector, you are going to end up with memory proportional to the next power of two after your actual requirements.  Most often, that can be considered amortized, too.

Comment: Note for pedants: the strategy used isn't technically doubling, but something that has similar effect, but with a multiplier that depends on the size of the vector, to try to minimize memory overhead while still being fast.